# How to use machine learning to create combine of opposite images side by side

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

Inspired by: [Two Worlds Pictures](https://www.instagram.com/ugurgallen/)

[image]
[image]

I just want to create a Machine Learning Model that can automatically combine the opposite images into 1 image.

I am thinking about 2 possible solutions:

1. [Pose Estimation](https://medium.com/tensorflow/move-mirror-an-ai-experiment-with-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-using-tensorflow-js-2f7b769f9b23): Detect humans and their poses from image data and search an archive by pose, but totally out of context.
2. [Land Lines](https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/2016/land-lines): explore similar lines.

It's just my ideas, do you have any recommendations? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like GANs would work. It can use some base picture and change the context, add some opposite attributes. There is an example of Generative Adversarial Style Transfer Networks to clarify what I mean http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018_workshops/papers/w41/Palsson_Generative_Adversarial_Style_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf In this example age is change by the model and it looks very natural, therefor the state of appearance could be change too (from poor to rich or vice versa) 
https://neurohive.io/en/news/gated-gan-style-transfer-with-multiple-styles/
The first image with a girl conveys the idea of gan using, but it should be thought over more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I do not want to generate new images from 1 image, I want to find the opposite images from my dataset.

Comment: Ok, I see. You've proposed a very interesting challenge. Good luck :) Then object recognition would be more suitable perhaps to find firstly the same "objects", then classify position of a person on the image etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have plenty of examples of images combination, what you can do is using Deep Learning models with CNNs in order to assess if two images are compatible for combination or not: i.e. Supervised learning. The model would take two images as input and would output a probability of being combined together. It can be useful to find the most probable candidates for combining with a given image in a very big database